# Paint on the bumper

Tags: paint, bumper, trim

I've done a touch-up of some scratches on my paint, and a couple of drips went on the matt black bumper.  I tried to wipe it off but there is still some residue.  Tried WD40 on a microfibre cloth, to no effect.  I have some leftover T-Cut style stuff from a headlamp restoration kit, would that work?

Comment: What is the bumper material ? Is it painted /

Comment: It's black plastic, matt texture.

Comment: Experiment on a small area of the bumper that can't be seen, like the underside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is solid black plastic, an abrasive will remove it. something like 400 grit should make a matte surface ; you will need to practice, to much rubbing or too fine a grit will produce more shine -less matte. PS; My black plastic bumpers were yellow urethane under the paint.